# Listbox scrollbar doesn't follow selected item (with ICollectionView)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, observablecollection

I'm trying to implement the MVVM pattern in WPF. I've followed Jeremy Alles's [Very simple MVVM demo application](http://www.japf.fr/?p=137). I have a ListBox that has a binding to an ObservableCollection:

```
<ListBox
    Name="myListBox"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:PersonsView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I added an **ICollectionView** to manage the selected item on the ListBox. It also allows me to have two buttons that allow me to select the previous and next items in the list.

```
private void GoToPrevious()
{
    this.collectionView.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
}
private void GoToNext()
{
    this.collectionView.MoveCurrentToNext();
}
```

It all works great, however, when the selected item is below the displayed area of the listbox, the listbox's scrollbar doesn't move accordingly.

How can I synchronize the scrollbar/display area of the ListBox with the selected item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the answer.
I needed to use

```
myListBoxItem.BringIntoView();
```

The problem was that I didn't wanted to add any code-behind, as I am implementing MVVM.

The solution is using **Attached Behaviors**. Josh Smith has a great article about this: [Introduction to Attached Behaviors in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx).

I adedd a Setter to the style of the items in the ListBox:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter
            Property="custom:ListBoxItemBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected"
            Value="True" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And added the following class (only changed TreeView from Josh's article to ListBox):

```
public static class ListBoxItemBehavior
{
    #region IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected

    public static bool GetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(ListBoxItem listBoxItem)
    {
        return (bool)listBoxItem.GetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(
      ListBoxItem listBoxItem, bool value)
    {
        listBoxItem.SetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ListBoxItemBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged));

    static void OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged(
      DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = depObj as ListBoxItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OnListBoxItemSelected;
        else
            item.Selected -= OnListBoxItemSelected;
    }

    static void OnListBoxItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only react to the Selected event raised by the ListBoxItem
        // whose IsSelected property was modified.  Ignore all ancestors
        // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Selected fired.
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
            return;

        ListBoxItem item = e.OriginalSource as ListBoxItem;
        if (item != null)
            item.BringIntoView();
    }

    #endregion // IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected
}
```

It works!!